# Installing TeX Live from source breaks manpages

Tags: texlive, installing, ubuntu

When I install the latest TeX Live in Linux Mint 21 64-bit, and add the binaries to my `$PATH`, my manpages break, but when I rm them using the following commands:

`rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2022`
`rm -rf ~/.texlive2022`

`man` mysteriously works again. Is this a bug, or am I just making a rookie mistake?

Comment: you presumably did something wrong (eg set MANPATH incorrectly) but you have provided no information not even said what went wrong. `man` fails to start? crashes? starts but can not find the files? ...?

Comment: Okay, maybe you're right, not a whole lot of good documentation you can follow to get a good install. Even the official TeX live doesn't provide exact details to follow to get a good install, I'm forced to using the outdated system distribution due to this issue. I'll try to reinstall, post the log and see what happens.

Comment: Alright, I've determined that it only breaks when you `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`, since I haven't put it into .bashrc yet, I can restart the terminal and it clears. When I use man before the export, it works fine. Executing man after entering the export command gives me `Cannot start application: Permission denied`. I've put my install log [here](https://gist.github.com/applecuckoo/c115f42053bfd750a8ae6bf54ea13d8e#file-install-tl-log).

Comment: That's weird, man (by default) is nroff/groff based so doesn't use tex at all. Do you have a pdf based man viewer? what does `type --all man` report after you set PATH ?  you could ask on the linux site how to trace where man is failing as it looks like an issue with man rather than texlive

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It spits out this: `man is /usr/local/bin/man`  
`man is /usr/bin/man`  
`man is /bin/man`

Comment: is /usr/local/bin/man a  system  man or is it really a local version. Either way I fear we can't debug here, just installing texlive and setting PATH works for literally millions of people, something on your system is breaking man, but I'm not sure how to debug that or even what application it tried to run that had wrong permissions